# using regex_findall to filter output

Tags: regex, ansible, yaml

I am using regex find_all to filter the output of network command, I've tested the regex with the output using regex101 and I'am sure it's correct, the output is also as expected but when I try to filter I think it don't match in the playbook. I always get a blank msg as a result.

```
- name: extract env
 lineinfile:                                 
   line: "{{ env.stdout[0] }}"
   dest: "{{ output_path }}/env_of_{{inventory_hostname}}.csv"
   create: True
-  debug:
   msg: "{{ env.stdout[0] | regex_findall('^.*one minute: (\\d+%); five.*$') }}"
```

The output should be a number in percent but this is what I get:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
task path: /ansible/testcsv.yml:60
ok: [R1] => {
"msg": []
 }
ok: [R2] => {
"msg": []
 }
ok: [R3] => {
"msg": []
 }
```

Comment: Please overhaul your question, add more detail; how are we supposed to know why the regex doesn't match if we can't see what's actually in `env.stdout[0]` ?

Comment: The content is too large to share but the regex should match on this section : CPU utilization for five seconds: 13%/0%; one minute: 6%; five minutes: 4% ; only the value for 1 minute would be extracted

Answer (score 0):

Regex' uses backslash escape, and so does YAML when you are using double quoted scalars, as you do. That is asking for problems and unreadability.

You would at either need to double and backslashes in your value for `msg`, use single quotes (within which only single quotes can, and need to be, escaped by doubling them), or, and that is the best solution by far, use YAML's blocks style literal scalar (with appropriate chomping):

```
- name: extract env
 lineinfile:                                 
   line: |-
     {{ env.stdout[0] }}
   dest: |-
      {{ output_path }}/env_of_{{inventory_hostname}}.csv
   create: True
-  debug:
   msg: |-
      {{ env.stdout[0] | regex_findall('^.*one minute: (\\d+%); five.*$') }}
```

Comment: At first it was returning an error message before executing the playbook, so I've doubled the backslash in this regex in order to fix it. Also with YAML's blocks style returns the same result : an empty message